# Exporting Visio drawing to PDF, but the text in the shapes are not searchable in the resulting PDF document

Tags: pdf, search, conversion, export, microsoft-visio

I have a Visio drawing that is comprised of an image that has been imported into Visio, then rectangles are scattered throughout the document; each of these rectangles has a unique piece of text inside of it that represent unique objects. When I've used the three different ways native to my version of Visio (2016), the text in the resulting PDF documents cannot be found when using the Ctrl + F search function.

Is there an option I'm not selecting? How can I make it so that the text in the resulting PDF is searchable?

Comment: One can usually use Adobe Acrobat (not Reader) to make an image editable and therefore searchable

Comment: There's text in this image that I don't want converted to be searchable. I only want the text that I included in the shapes in Visio to be searchable.

Comment: Adobe Acrobat can make editable.  Once anything is editable it is also searchable. The 2 things go together

Comment: Yes, that's my point. I want the text from the rectangles to be searchable as part of the export process from Visio so that I don't have to make all of the text searchable/editable using Acrobat.

Comment: PDF is a standard.  Try exporting to a different format (say unique to Visio). Otherwise I do not know

Comment: I've just created a simple Visio document containing a rectangle shape and the word "hello". Saved to PDF and opened in Firefox, text was found ok, opened in Acrobat, Ctrl-F - text was found ok. Problem not found.

Answer (score 0):

Had same problem. Some texts can be found with Ctrl-F, some not.
Tracked this down to texts with a scaling <> 100%. Shape texts with a scaling other than 100% cannot be found in Visio generated PDF. With Visio 2010 this still works fine. Guess this is an issue with newer Visio updates.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).